# Place value into Excel cell through xlwings based on row number and column number

Tags: python-3.x, xlwings

Suppose I want to place value `123` into Excel cell `A2` which corresponds to `row=1`, `column=2`. How do I do this through xlwings?

I am using xlwings 0.19.4, python 3.7, Excel 2016.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer my own question.

```
wb = xw.Book.caller()
sheet = wb.sheets[0]
row_num = 1
col_num = 2
sheet.range(row_num, col_num).value = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about previous versions of xlwings but this should work

```
wb = xw.Book(filename)
sh = wb.sheets[0]
sh.cells(1, 2).value=123
```